# Why can't I interact with subviews?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ipad

I have a view controller where I can add several subviews with a `LongPressGesture`. For each `subview` I provide a `TapGesture` that should open a `popover` for this view (see picture below).

My problem is, that I can only open the popover for the last subview I added. So why can't I interact with the other subviews anymore?
This is my first App in Swift, so it would be nice if someone could help me.

Some code for you:
This is the LongPressGesture on the root view controller that creates a new subview.

```
@IBAction func onLongPress(_ gesture : UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {

    let position: CGPoint = gesture.location(in: view)

    if(gesture.state == .began) {
        let subview = MySubview(position: position)
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleTap(_:)))
        subview.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

        view.addSubview(subview)
    }
    else if (gesture.state == .ended) {
        let subview = self.view.subviews.last
        self.openContextMenu(for: subview)
    }
}
```

**ViewController with subviews:-**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When reacting to an event (long press in your case) only the first responder will handle the event. When adding subviews to a view, all the subviews are added one in front of another. So the last added subview will handle the event - if it is listening for the event. If you need a specific subview to handle the event, you can bring it to front as

```
parentView.bringSubviewToFront(view: subView)
```

Alternatively, you can also disable other subviews as

```
subView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

Comment: Thanks so far, but my problem is that no matter on which subview I click, the popover should appear next to the clicked view. Is that even possible or is the layer system not designed for that use case?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a solution for my problem. The good thing is, that it only detects touches in the frames of the subviews.

In my root view controller I added:

```
    var isPanGesture = false

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        isPanGesture = true

        if let subview = touches.first!.view as? MySubview {
            let position = touches.first!.location(in: self.view)
            link.center = position
        }
    }
    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if let subview = touches.first!.view as? MySubview {
            if(!isPanGesture) {
                self.openContextMenu(for: subview)
            }
            isPanGesture = false
        }
    }
```